# how to make a kik bot respond in groupchat via the kik api?

Tags: kik

I'm trying to build a bot for kik.

Example: when I mention @weather in kik groupchat, the weathebot responds in that group with the current weather.

I'm trying to reproduce exactly that, but can't find any information about it.

I tried /broadcast and /messages endpoint, but it always responds with 402 where 1-on-1 messages work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you send a message with the chatId being the same as the received message it will go to the group conversation

Comment: What do you put for the "to" though? When I try this (using the same chatId), I get back {"message":"You are not allowed to send a message to this conversation","error":"Forbidden"}

Comment: You can set the "to" field to be the same as the "from"

chatId should just be message['chatId']